# Should other language except English be allowed in question or answer comment section ?

Tags: discussion

I was checking main site questions, found out OP and the one who answered has started commenting in their native language. Should it be allowed ?

Question Link: [adding gif on toolbar in android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49023525/1944896)

**Screenshot of the comments:**

[image]

Comment: Flag them as "no longer needed", we will remove them.

Comment: Also, that question is "Too Broad".